# c# type References (vs C)

Tags: c#, pointers

How c# references work if, classes are references
`class1 a = new class1();`
 so  address named "a" contains
address of the object indicating mem[0] ,So it's a pointer

why

```
method(class1 a);
```

copies value of object to a local method instance and not address of mem[0]?
does it implicitly de-reference (`*`) a?
if so   ,then `ref` modifier cancels it?

lets say a class defines a type of an address  to addresses that point to  various points of an object.  i still cant get to the end of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you may want to think about C# class variables as (safe) C pointers, in this sense. They just don't allow you to manipulate where they point in memory (the run-time is even allowed to re-allocate and move them).

If your `class1` is a class type (as opposed to a struct type or ValueType), then you are however not correct that `method` will copy the whole `a` object. It will instead act as if you had passed a pointer in C. But just like in C, `*p1==*p2` and `p1==p2` but `&p1!=&p2`

Since class variables store mere references (similar to C pointers), if `method` mutates the object referred by `a`, these mutations will remain after `method` returns. Passing a class variable by ref is then analogous to passing a pointer to a pointer in C; but it can hardly ever be a good design idea in C#.

This is how *class* variables behave (including strings). However there are also value types (all basic types except string and object, and structs) which are copied when assigned or passed to methods, unless passed with a qualifier such as `ref` or `out`.

Further reading:

- [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)
- [MSDN: Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)
- [MSDN: Value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)

Comment: "Class variables are passed by reference" - no, they're not. The value of the variable (the reference) is passed by value. Saying they're passed by reference implies that adding `ref` to a reference type parameter would make no difference, and that's not true.

Comment: "Objects of a class type are passed by reference" isn't much better. It's really not that complicated: the value of a reference type variable is a reference, not an object. The object isn't passed at all: either a reference is passed by value, or the variable is passed by reference (for a `ref` parameter). Talking about the object being passed by reference ends up being more complicated *and* gets into trouble around null references, too.

Comment: Tried more precisely

Comment: My assumption was wrong(a course misled me)... method(a)   copies indeed the value of the address named 'a'

Answer (score 2):

> why `method(class1 a)` copies value of object to a local method

This is a wrong assumption. The method parameter `a` contains a reference to the object. If you use `method(ref class1 a)`, then you get a reference to the variable passed to the method, which in turn contains a reference to the object

Given

```
class1 a = new class1();
method(ref a);
```

In the method, you could assign a new object to the parameter and this would change `a`!

```
void method(ref class1 b)
{
    b = new class1(); // This changes a!
}
```

If the `ref` keyword is missing, the method gets a copy of the reference (not a copy of the object!)

```
void method(class1 b)
{
    b = new class1(); // This does NOT change a.

    // But
    b.IntProperty = 5; // This changes a property of a.
}
```

In C# you don't have to use `*`. C# knows which types are reference and which ones are value types and treats them accordingly.

For a normal parameter:

- For value types: a copy of the value is passed.
- For reference types: a copy of the value is passed (yes!). The value just happens to be a reference (or `null`). I.e., no object is copied.

For `ref` parameters:

- For value types: a reference to the variable containing the value is passed.
- For reference types: a reference to the variable containing a reference (or `null`) is passed.

In other words, for `ref` parameters, the parameter name is just an alias for the variable used in the method call.

---

If you find this confusing, it helps to configure the colors in the editor to help to differentiate between reference and value types. In Visual Studio: Go to menu `Tools` > `Options...`, then `Environment` > `Fonts and Colors` and change the color of `User Types - Structures` (i.e. of value types) to display as a different color as classes (I am using Olive). There are a few other `User Types` you can change (I am using Red for delegates, a dark Orange for enums, Purple for interfaces and a kind of neon green for type parameters.

Comment: "the reference to the object is passed by reference" - I think you're making things too complicated. The variable is passed by reference, for all `ref` parameters, whether that's a value type or a reference type. It's important that it's the variable specified as the argument that's passed by reference - not just any "reference to the object". If there are two variables `a` and `b` whose values happen to refer to the same object, and you call `Method(ref a)` that method can change the value of `a`, but it can't change the value of `b`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, not easy to explain (you're much better in this discipline). I reworded my answer.

Comment: Definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to understand how methods are called and how objects are allocated in the memory.

All class types are of reference types in C# - inheriting from **System.Object**.

> Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and
>   provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate
>   base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the
>   type hierarchy.

Reference: [MSDN Documentation of System.Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Meaning, they would be allocated in heap.  Their reference would be copied to some place.  The variable holds that place where the reference is copied.

In case of method call, the address of an object is copied to call stack.    It is pointing to the same address.

So if you change any property (of value type) of the class, you will still be able to access the changed value in the caller method - even though you don't use ref keyword.

```
void Method(Class A)
```

Technically, ref keyword provides same address location - instead of copying this address to new location.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "By default, all values are of reference types in C#" - while I don't understand it, I can't tell whether or not I agree with it.

Comment: That's still odd - because "by default" suggests that it's *possible* to have class types that aren't reference types, and that's not the case.

Comment: Definitely better.